# requestAccessToAccountsWithType completion not being called

Tags: objective-c, twitter, accounts, social-framework

When I run  [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType: ...] I am getting no response. My completion handler isn't being called. However I do have access to twitter.

```
    //  Step 0: Check that the user has local Twitter accounts
    if ([SLComposeViewController
     isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        NSLog(@"OH YES!!!");
        //  Step 1:  Obtain access to the user's Twitter accounts
        ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
        NSLog(@"OH YES!!!");

        [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:nil
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Im in!");
            if (granted == YES)
            {
                NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [_accountStore
                                            accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

                if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
                {
                    ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                    NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount.userFullName);
                    NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount.username);
                    NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount.credential);
                    NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount.identifier);

                }
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Failed muahahaha");
            }
        }];
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make shure _accountStore is initialized for example with

```
_accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
```

Comment: I had figured out my issue yesterday. I did have it initialized, but in viewDidLoad. I didn't think it was an issue until I moved it into my function. 

Out of curiosity, why didn't it work when I had _accountStore initialized in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Also, I forgot to add, that I had apparently blocked my app from using twitter. Slip of the finger lol 

Once I reset the settings on my device and changed that line of code, everything was fine.